# Which one is bigger ,which one is smaller?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$a=1000+\frac{1}{1000}\\b=1000+\frac{1}{1000+\dfrac{1}{1000+\dfrac{1}{1000}}}\\c=1000+\dfrac{1}{1000+\dfrac{1}{1000+\dfrac{1}{1000+\dfrac{1}{1000}}}}$$ Is there a simple idea to describe this problem to the students ,that which one is bigger and which is the smallest ?
I mean with out using calculator .The students of k10
I am thankful in advance for your idea .

Comment: You left out one, between a and b. This is called a continued fraction, if you keep going. If you put in the missing one, they alternate below and above the limit, which is irrational.   $$   \frac{1000 + \sqrt {1000004}}{2} $$

Comment: @WillJagy:First thank you about attention .I know that is continued fraction ,but I wanna describe it to k10 students which do not knowledge about $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$

Comment: I guess I would tell them first the same material, but instead of 1000, show the calculation with 1 and then the calculation with 2. With 1, you can go ahead and work out the actual fractions for the first few steps,

Comment: Wait?  Just those three finite ones?  Obviously $a > 1000$ so $\frac 1a < \frac 1{1000}$ so $a = 1000 + \frac 1000 > 1000 + \frac1a = b$  and $b = 1000 + \frac 1a < 1000 + \frac 1b = c$.  The real question is how to extend is is the a lower limit.

Comment: Let them guess that they can put a in b .....and make deductions about b compared to a...

Comment: Perhaps a good way to teach about induction and also teach how to use definitions.  With a(1)=1000+1/1000 and a(n+1)=1000 +1/a(n). we have a=a(1), b=a(3),c=a(4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two fractions with the same numerator, then the one with the bigger denominator is the smaller fraction. Whatever those expressions equal that are added to the $1000$ from the first denominator, they're not negative.

Thus, since $a$ has the smallest denominator, it is the largest number.

Thinking in this way, from the "innermost" denominator out, you should be able to determine whether $b$ or $c$ is larger. In particular, the third denominator of $c$ is bigger than the third denominator of $b$. (For, $1000+x$ is bigger than $1000$.) Thus, the second denominator of $c$ is *smaller* than the second denominator of $b$. Et cetera.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes it helps ...for the denominator has to be more than 1 otherwise the more it's close to zero the bigger is the number...

Answer (score 1):

Let g(x) = 1000 + 1/x.  g(x) is a decreasing function of x, whose fixed point $x^*$ Will has already worked out.  g(g(a)) will be an increasing function.

So, we are interested in a,g(g(a))=b,g(g(g(g(a))))=c, we would have $a<b<c<x^*$

We reason about the order of a,b,c using the fact that g(g(a))>a, etc.